# Autolink property for TextView is not working in Android?

Tags: android

I am using below code for opening dial up when clicking on TextView. The problem is it is not working on samsung tablet 10 inch device. It is opening a dialogue box with options 'saving contact' and 'close' rather than opening dial up. I have tested using the same code on Lenovo 7 inch(using api level 19) and Motorolla droid turbo (using api level 22) it is working fine but samsung 10 inch tablet (using api level 21) it is showing dialogue with mentioned options.Am I missing something or this is api specific behavior? Below is the code.

```
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white_color"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoLink="phone"
            android:textColorLink="@color/white_color"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_address"
            android:text="PH: (800) 579-4875 (310) 534-1505" />
```

Comment: the problem is probably the samsung firmware, it is usually a whole lot  different to other android devices and behave in strange ways for common use cases

Comment: yes, may be. I was thinking the same thing, but was not sure about the bevaior.

Comment: @AbdulWaheed your samsung tablet 10 inch it's have calling feature?

Comment: no it does not have calling feature..

Comment: AAhhhh I get the point now...thanks to keep my direction there..

Answer (score 2):

I am posting the answer. It may be helpful for others. The problem was not in the code or in xml. The problem was with the tablet hardware. My device does not have calling feature that means I don't have sim card slot in my tablet that's why I was not getting dial up screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup click event handler to start dial. It must work for different firmware.

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);

        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "phone number here"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
TextView phone = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.idPhone);
phone.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);
```